# Jackson ConstructorProperties ignores properties names

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, xmlmapper

I am really confused how jackson (2.9.6 version) `ObjectMapper` works with `@ConstructorProperties` annotation.

It seems that mapper ignores property names which are present in a `@ConstructorProperties`annotation value method.

What's even more interesting - mapper works correctly regardless of properties names.

What I am talking about?

Let's consider custom XmlMapper:

```
private static final ObjectMapper XML_MAPPER = new XmlMapper()
            .setAnnotationIntrospector(
                    AnnotationIntrospector.pair(
                            new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(),
                            new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector()
                    )
            )
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
            .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE);
```

and simple Data Transfer Object (DTO):

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "person")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    static class Person {
        @XmlAttribute
        final int age;

        @XmlAttribute
        final String name;

        @XmlAttribute
        final LocalDate dateOfBirth;

        @ConstructorProperties({"age","name","dateOfBirth"})
        public Person(int age, String name, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "age=" + age +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

I created test to reproduce the issue:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Check xml deseralization for Person class")
void deserialization() throws IOException {
    String xml = "<person age=\"26\" name=\"Fred\" date-of-birth=\"1991-11-07\"/>";
    Person person = XML_MAPPER.readValue(xml, Person.class);
    Assertions.assertEquals("Person{age=26, name='Fred', dateOfBirth=1991-11-07}", person.toString());
}
```

It's strange for me why test is passed regardless of `@ConstructorProperties` annotation. The test passed with annotation

```
        @ConstructorProperties({"a","b","c"})
        public Person(int age, String name, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        }
```

Is it a magic? How jackson processes this annotation? What is an equivalent in jackson annotations to ConstructorProperties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's passing because the `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` can determine the property names from the `@XmlAttribute` annotations.

The doc on `AnnotationIntrospectorPair` says:

> Helper class that allows using 2 introspectors such that one
>   introspector acts as the primary one to use; and second one
>   as a fallback used if the primary does not provide conclusive
>   or useful result for a method.

The `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` (which understands the `@ConstructorProperties` annotation) isn't being used at all.

If you remove all the JAXB annotations your test will only pass when the correct names are specified in `@ConstructorProperties`.

If you want to do it "the jackson way", then remove the JAXB annotations and the `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` completely (just drop the call to `setAnnotationIntrospector`, the mapper will default to using the `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`).

Deserialisation will work, but you'll have to add some jackson native annotations if you want to achieve the same serialised form:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "person")
static class Person {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    final int age;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    final String name;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    final LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @ConstructorProperties({"age", "name", "dateOfBirth"})
    public Person(int age, String name, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    //...
```